# Pivot with Temp Table (definition for column must include data type) -- SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

The following is returning two errors:
'The definition for column '0.63' must include a data type.'
'The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.'

I understand that I need to assign a data type to the columns that are being inserted into my temp table I don't quite understand how to do this with dynamic code however. Honestly it would help greatly if I could get some explanation on how the @cols variable code is working and then help with my specific issue. fldPK is data type INT and the Pivot fields i.e. @cols, are all FLOAT data type.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

    select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(fldCI) 
                        from FN_qryT_1()
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ,1,1,'')

    set @query = 'SELECT fldPK, ' + @cols + '
                    FROM 

                    (
                    SELECT   fldPK
                            ,fldNI
                            ,fldCI
                    FROM FN_qryT_1()    
                    ) as x
                    PIVOT
                    (
                        Sum(fldNI) FOR fldCI IN (' + @cols + ')
                    ) as p 

                DECLARE @TPS TABLE
                (
                    ' + @cols + ' 
                )

                INSERT @TPS (' + @cols + ')

                SELECT fldPK, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
                FROM @TPS
                WHERE ((([1])<10)) OR ((([2])<10)) OR ((([3])<10))'

                exec sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: Why are you trying to insert the results on a table variable?, you won't be able to query it outside the scope of the execution of the dynamic SQL (So, after the `exec sp_executesql @query`, the table variable doesn't exists)

Comment: I need to return and display the results in some way and this is the best way I have found so far.